# Node js authentication system for content uploaded to s3

Tags: node.js, authentication, amazon-s3, microservices

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to check if the user has access to files located on s3.

Right now I have only two content status public and private but when one user copy the file URL and the uploader change state to private the first user still get access to this file.

I know I need to create some kind of service to authorize users but I don't know how to return data to them without exposing the s3 url

Comment: You could consider using [presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html) if that model fits your application.

Comment: Cognito does this pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for answer the presigned url is great but it will be hard to implement in dash and hls.